# How to determine the voltage range of a microphone output?

Tags: microphone, decibel

I have an analog microphone: [PMM-3738-VM1010-R](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/334/PMM-3738-VM1010-R-1113381.pdf). I want to know what will be the voltage range of the microphone's output at a specific threshold level, let's say 89 dB threshold (different thresholds are mentioned in the datasheet, 89 dB is one of them).

The datasheet provides sensitivity and as far as I understand, sensitivity of -38dB corresponds to 13 mV, but I don't know how to use it to define the voltage range of the microphone.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

EDIT: I have found the values using an oscilloscope, but it would be great to know the theoretical way as well.